# В server.js указать параметры, чтобы тянул стили и скрипты

Tags: node.js, jquery, javascript

Здравствуйте!

На сайте имеется дирректория с `/node/chat/server.js`. Код написан с использование express.js
тут же в коре лежит папки:

```
public/css/chat/chat.css
public/js/chat/chat.js
```

Сама страница отображения должна быть по адресу www.site.ru/chat
Как в server.js для app.configure указать эти параметры, чтобы тянул стили и скрипты?

```
app.configure(function(){
    app.set('port', process.env.PORT || 8080);
    //app.use(express.favicon());
    app.use(express.logger('short'));
    app.use(app.router);
    app.use("/styles", express.static(__dirname + '/public/css/chat/chat.css'));
    app.use("/js", express.static(__dirname + '/public/js/chat/chat.js'));
});
```

Очень необходима ваша подсказка

Comment: как я понял, код: app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public')); указывает на то, что в папке с server.js должна быть папка public в которой папка css/chat.css и js/script.js и тогда, там где прослушивается app.get в том файле(пути), достаточно указать /js/script.js, /css/chat.css, чтобы стили и скрипты подключились. Сделал так. но не сработало...

Answer (score 1):

C трудом понял что именно вы хотите: чтобы файлы находились по укороченному пути, или чтобы файл (именно один файл) выдавался при обращении к пути? В данный момент, файл 'chat.js' выдается при обращении на '/js', вы уверены, что ожидали именно такое поведение? Обычно подключают директории с файлами, а не сам файл:

```
app.use("/styles", express.static(__dirname + '/public/css/chat'));
app.use("/js", express.static(__dirname + '/public/js/chat'));
```

Тогда загрузка скрипта на странице происходит таким путем:

```
<script src='/js/chat.js'></script>
```

Если в вашем коде все правильно, и я ничего не понимаю, то загрузка скрипта должна проходить так:

```
<script src='/js'></script>
```

Но я не уверен в работоспособности такого решения.

Comment: Денис - спасибо. попробую. Загляните сюда еще пару раз - я дам ответ.